# Add List Throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, unsupportedoperation

I have 4 functions with same get...() method, and I only change the name or identifier, but I've got different result with the fourth which is when to adding new item to list, it throws java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException. I assure you, I've already double checked all 4 functions and their relations, but have no idea why the fourth function like this.

```
public List<PropertyAttribute> getAttributes() {
    if (selectedCode == null)
        return null;

    Criteria criteria = this.propertyAttributeDAO.createCriteria();
    FilterUtils.byField(criteria, "propertyCode", this.selectedCode, true);
    List<PropertyAttribute> list = criteria.list();

    if (isNewAttribute()) {
        list.add(0, this.curAttribute); //this line that throws exception
    }

    return list;
}
```

UPDATE STACK TRACE:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148)
        at bos.web.pages.instrument.ViewProperty.getAttributes(ViewProperty.java:654)
        at $InternalPropertyConduit_237587e282284.get(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.bindings.PropBinding.get(PropBinding.java:59)
```

Comment: Can you post the whole stackTrace? It may also be interesting to know which `List` implementation `criteria.list()` produces

Comment: I would guess like @nbokmans that the `criteria.list()` use a `Arrays.asList()` (or equivalent) returning an instance that don't support the `add` operation.

Comment: You have your answer then, see [AbstractList documention](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html), it will be quite obvious what is the problem. And the solution as been given.

Comment: @AxelH thanks, will see it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's clearly documented, don't assume it's safe to modify a list you received from another method. Even if it doesn't throw an exception, it may be altering critical state (if it's not implemented safely). Copy it to a new list and you can do whatever you like:

```
List<PropertyAttribute> list = new ArrayList<>(criteria.list());
```

Comment: It works. But can you tell me why the other 3 functions did not throwing exception?

Comment: I don't see any other functions.